# Getting SQL Grammar exception while performing insert

Tags: java, spring

**Getting SQL Grammar exception on application screen.But same thing is working fine in local server. Below is the Error details.**

**javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet**

```
om.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.inventory.InvTrueUpController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4b33560.con_saveFleet()
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I don't see a `SQLGrammarException` in your stacktrace but without the actual Java code that is failing, this is impossible to answer

Comment: Could you please post the INSERT query ? Without it, it is almost impossible to help you...

Comment: in logs i am getting unique index violated error. java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TBCAM.COSAK_MDL_VR_MDL_MDL_VER_TYPID) violated

Comment: same thing is working fine in my local server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet. This the line which is showing as caused by

Comment: This probably means that you are trying to insert one or more rows that have the same primary key with rows already existing in your table. Ids / primary keys are unique for each row.

Comment: "*could not extract ResultSet" makes no sense together with a INSERT statement.  - please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the code that generates the error.

Comment: @petros there is unique index for mdl_ID and mdl_ver_typ_id column this is unique index which is getting violated fro mdl_ver_typ_id.

Comment: @Petros but how can same thing is working in my local server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is failing in DB insert query..there is only procedure call from java side.same column value is getting inserted which is causing the issue. But same thing is working fine my local server..how..?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the Java (and SQL) code that generates the error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name due to rules and regulation i can't able to post the code.one more thing its failing after 4 min only for different data sets

Answer (score 0):

1) Please crosscheck you are pointing to the same Database in Local vs TestEnvironment

2) some value coming from properties file, being used in index COSAK_MDL_VR_MDL_MDL_VER_TYPID

so this property will be different at TestEnvironment than at Local.

Comment: My local is pointing to the same Database which is used for real-time application.

Comment: My local code is same as Test Environment and DB pointing as well.But still it is working fine in local,  not in Test Environment. Strange but it's true